# How to insert a smaller image in an opencv Videocapture frame?

Tags: python, opencv

So, I have this code, I can easily add a text or any shape  in opencv frame.
But inserting an image on a frame is a very difficult one.
I want to insert a smaller image on a Videocapture frame, let say the image to be inserted is a 50x50 pixel.
Any idea on this?

```
import cv2
webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
insertImage = "sample.jpg" # size 50x50 
while True:
    rval = False
    while(not rval):
        (rval, frame) = webcam.read()
        if(not rval):
            print("Failed to open webcam. Trying again...")
    cv2.putText(frame, " image here ", (0,70),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.6, (255,0,0), 2)
    cv2.imshow('with image', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
webcam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenCv images are numpy arrays. As far as I know, OpenCv does not provide functions with which you can get what you want. The result can be achieved by manipulating arrays.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
if __name__ == '__main__':

    bigImage = cv2.imread("image1.png") #I don't have a webcam connected, so it's your frame
    smallImage = cv2.imread("image2.png") #50x50 for you
    height, width, channels = smallImage.shape
    offset = np.array((40, 50)) #top-left point from which to insert the smallest image. height first, from the top of the window
    bigImage[offset[0]:offset[0] + height, offset[1]:offset[1] + width] = smallImage
    cv2.imshow("test", bigImage)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

**Input**

- bigImage = big gray rectangle. It is your frame
- smallImage = small green rectangle. It is your 50x50 image

**Output**
[image]